# L2TP and so about DHCP

Tags: networking, local, dhcp, local-network, l2tp

I setup local network. I have 1 router and 2 devices, for sample. I setup L2TP server on the router and successfully connect devices to it.

```
ROUTER - 172.16.200.1
1 DEVICE - 172.16.200.2
2 DEVICE - 172.16.200.3
```

If i shutdown devices and **boot 2 device firstly**, and next 1 device. i see:

```
ROUTER - 172.16.200.1
1 DEVICE - 172.16.200.3
2 DEVICE - 172.16.200.2
```

I want, that router **remember MAC <-> Internal IP**. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Point-to-Point networks can't do it. We should use another protocol for this quest(for example OpenVPN)